# Configure interrupt handler for different GPIO pins of same port

Tags: c, interrupt-handling, gpio, mqx

I want to use 5 Gpios as user input buttons in mqx TWRK60D100. I followed configuration as

```
#define LEFT_BUTTON         (GPIO_PORT_E | GPIO_PIN26)  
#define LEFT_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ     (LWGPIO_MUX_E26_GPIO) 

#define RIGHT_BUTTON             (GPIO_PORT_A | GPIO_PIN19)
#define RIGHT_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ     (LWGPIO_MUX_A19_GPIO)

#define UP_BUTTON            (GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN5)
#define UP_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ    (LWGPIO_MUX_C5_GPIO)

#define DOWN_BUTTON              (GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN4)
#define DOWN_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ      (LWGPIO_MUX_C4_GPIO)

#define TEST_BUTTON              (GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN1)
#define TEST_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ      (LWGPIO_MUX_C1_GPIO)


#define BUTTON_PRESS_NOT_PENDING 0
#define LEFT_BUTTON_PRESSED     1
#define RIGHT_BUTTON_PRESSED    2
#define UP_BUTTON_PRESSED       3
#define DOWN_BUTTON_PRESSED     4
#define TEST_BUTTON_PRESSED     5

void int_service_routine(void *);

LWGPIO_STRUCT Left_Button;
LWGPIO_STRUCT Right_Button;
LWGPIO_STRUCT Up_Button;
LWGPIO_STRUCT Down_Button;
LWGPIO_STRUCT Test_Button;


volatile uint_8 Button_Press_Status = BUTTON_PRESS_NOT_PENDING;
/*ISR*-----------------------------------------------------
*
* Task Name    : int_service_routine
* Comments     :
* Button press ISR
*END*-----------------------------------------------------*/
void int_service_routine(void *pin)
{

    printf("In Isr %u \n",pin);

    if(pin==&Left_Button)
    {
        Button_Press_Status=LEFT_BUTTON_PRESSED;
    }
    else if(pin==&Right_Button)
    {
        Button_Press_Status=RIGHT_BUTTON_PRESSED;
    }
    else if(pin==&Up_Button)
    {
        Button_Press_Status=UP_BUTTON_PRESSED;
    }
    else if(pin==&Down_Button)
    {
        Button_Press_Status=DOWN_BUTTON_PRESSED;
    }
    else if(pin==&Test_Button)
    {
        Button_Press_Status=TEST_BUTTON_PRESSED;
    }

    lwgpio_int_clear_flag((LWGPIO_STRUCT_PTR) pin);
}

void Individual_Button_Config(LWGPIO_STRUCT_PTR button_name, 
       LWGPIO_PIN_ID pin_id,uint_32 button_mux_irq)
{

    /*
     Open the pin for input, initialize interrupt and set handler.
     */
    /* opening pins for input */
    if (!lwgpio_init(button_name, pin_id, 
             LWGPIO_DIR_INPUT,LWGPIO_VALUE_NOCHANGE)) 
    {
        printf("Initializing button GPIO as input failed.\n");
        _task_block();
    }


    /* Some platforms require to setup MUX to IRQ functionality,
     for the rest just set MUXto GPIO functionality */
    lwgpio_set_functionality(button_name, button_mux_irq);
    lwgpio_set_attribute(button_name, LWGPIO_ATTR_PULL_UP, LWGPIO_AVAL_ENABLE);

    /* enable gpio functionality for given pin, react on falling edge */
    if (!lwgpio_int_init(button_name, LWGPIO_INT_MODE_FALLING)) 
    {
        printf("Initializing button GPIO for interrupt failed.\n");
        _task_block();
    }

    /* install gpio interrupt service routine */
    _int_install_isr(lwgpio_int_get_vector(button_name), 
               int_service_routine, (void *) button_name);
    /* set the interrupt level, and unmask the 
       interrupt in interrupt controller*/
    _bsp_int_init(lwgpio_int_get_vector(button_name), 3, 0, TRUE);
    /* enable interrupt on GPIO peripheral module*/
    lwgpio_int_enable(button_name, TRUE );

    printf("\n Button pin has been configured as input GPIO interrupt pin.\n"); 
}

/*
 * Function Name    : Button_Init
 * Returned Value    : None
 * Comments          : This function will initialise gpio buttons as input 
 * 
 */
void Button_Init(void) 
{
    //Configuring Left Button 
    Individual_Button_Config(&Left_Button,LEFT_BUTTON,LEFT_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ);
    //Configuring Right Button 
    Individual_Button_Config(&Right_Button,RIGHT_BUTTON,RIGHT_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ);
    //Configuring Up Button 
    Individual_Button_Config(&Up_Button,UP_BUTTON,UP_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ);
    //Configuring Down Button 
    Individual_Button_Config(&Down_Button,DOWN_BUTTON,DOWN_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ);
    //Configuring Test Button 
    Individual_Button_Config(&Test_Button,TEST_BUTTON,TEST_BUTTON_MUX_IRQ);
}
```

Interrupt handling of different pins say `(GPIO_PORT_E | GPIO_PIN26) ,(GPIO_PORT_A | GPIO_PIN19)` worked fine.
But from `(GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN5), (GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN4), (GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN1),` only last configured `(GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN1)` was only worked.Other pin's interrupt handler get executes repeatedly without clearing interrupt flag.
When i commented `(GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN1)` pin configuration, `(GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN4)` worked fine but problem remained with `(GPIO_PORT_C | GPIO_PIN5).`

When I looked the address of pin in the interrupt handler, all of the port c interrupts show the address of last configured `GPIO C PIN1`.

What could be wrong with my code?

How to configure interrupt handler for different pins of same port?

Comment: `_bsp_int_init()` shouldn't be called for *user* code.  This is a BSP hook.  The *GPIO* layer should be agnostic to your BSP.  Are you sure it is right to call this function?  It would help to trim your code down to a minimum.

Comment: maybe this can help you: [MQX configure interrupts on an input pin example code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482378/mqx-configure-interrupts-on-an-input-pin-example-code-tutorial/22564062#22564062). Sry @artlessnoise.